# How would I execute a command at the position of every block of a certain type?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a beam of particles in replacement of a beacon beam. I have tried making a new model and texture but there seems to be no information on how to change a model that doesn't appear anywhere in the jar file. I have a command that will execute at every instance of a block: `/particle minecraft:glow_squid_ink ~ ~ ~ 0.1 100 0.1 0 2500 force`, but I can't seem to find a command that can execute at multiple positions unless there is an entity involved. To my knowledge, beacons are not entities and therefore cannot be detected by arguments like `execute as` or `at`, since those return entity arguments, and arguments like `if` will return a specific location rather than a range. I don't mind making a simple plugin if necessary, but I would rather keep it command block based if possible.

My end goal is simply a different looking beacon beam since the vanilla one is boring. If there isn't a simple solution that my monkey brain can process, then I don't mind doing it manually by entering the beams locations in by hand. If someone can show me how to make a model for this like I originally intended, that would be much appreciated since I'm more familiar with resource packs than plugins. (Version is 1.19.3 and I am running Iris+Sodium, but other than that it's vanilla)

Comment: You're right about the splitting of a command: Commands can only "select" entities, not blocks. You cannot execute at a certain block type without knowing its exact location. There are some (performance heavy) ways to scan through a region of blocks to check for the one you're looking for, but that's unfeasible for an entire gameworld. What you probably want to do instead is do some [raycasting](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/wiki/questions/raycast/) whenever a player places a beacon then mark the position of said beacon with an entity. Or just hardcode a few positions.

Comment: You could use the raycasting/scan Plagiatus mentioned along with the scoreboard for placed beacons. It should be ok to do a heavy scan only once!

Comment: I suggest scanning blocks only when a player places a block and summoning an invisible entity such as a marker armorstand inside them. I think you can do this with a scoreboard objective minecraft.custom:minecraft.used (or something like that). To decrease performance impact of the scan even further you can use caret notation by centering the start position around ^ ^ ^3. then use /execute if block to check each block in a small cube for beacons. You can /kill all armorstands with a certain tag that are not inside a beacon. Finally, summon the particles from the armor stand or a bit above it.

Comment: @Samstercraft using invisible armorstands as markers is so 1.8 ;). Area Effect Clouds are the better marker entity since 1.9, an argument can be made for item frames since 1.16 when they added invisible and fixed, and currently **since 1.17 the `marker` entity is the best marker entity** if all you need is to mark a position.